# Load a custom nx.Graph class in PyTorch Geometric

Tags: pytorch, networkx, pytorch-geometric

I've write a custom class from nx.Graph here is the **init** method:

```
class NetlistGraph(nx.Graph):
    """
    A custom graph class to load netlist.json files into a networkx bipartide graph.
    
    If the netlist_names parameter is not specified, the netlists will 
    be named after their file name.
    """
    def __init__(self, netlist_path: str, 
                 add_attributes: Optional[List[str]] = None):
        """Initializes the NetlistGraph class.

        Args:
            netlist_path (str): path to the netlist file
            add_attributes (Optional[List[str]], optional): list of attributes to be added to the   graph. Defaults to None.
        """
        # Super class constructor
        super().__init__()
        
        # Create a logger object for this class
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        
        # Store the netlist name from the filepath
        self._dirname, filename = os.path.split(netlist_path)
        self._netlist_name, _ = os.path.splitext(filename)
        
        # Attribute to check if the graph store attributes from the netlist 
        if add_attributes:
            self.attrs = list(set(add_attributes))
            self.has_attributes = True
        else:
            self.attrs = None
            self.has_attributes = False
           
        if isinstance(netlist_path, str):
            # Load the netlist file
            netlist = self._load_netlist(netlist_path)
            # Get devices
            devices = self._get_devices(netlist)
            # TODO: Clean and one-hot encode devices attributes
            # Add devices and respective attributes to the graph
            self.add_devices(devices)
            
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'netlist_path must be a string, not {type(netlist_path)}')
```

I've tried to load the class in pytorch geometric using from_networkx(G) but it give me an error:

> H = G.**class**()
> TypeError: NetlistGraph.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'netlist_path'